# Ensure = at the start of a form input field is never used

Tags: javascript, html, regex, forms, vue.js

I am looking for a solution to ensure a `=` character is not used on any input within a form.

```
    <form>
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required="">
        <input name="last name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
        <input name="idnumber" type="number" placeholder="ID Number">
    </form>
```

I now the type fields of email and number should prevent this, but am unsure whether this can be hacked. So perhaps use some validation on those too

I thought regex might be the answer, it is almost working. Just needs a tweak (Both results should just show the text "test1" and "test2" with the = stripped out)
https://regex101.com/r/faYiuB/1/

Could this be incorporated into the input field with regex like my first attempt below?

```
<input type="text" pattern="^[^\=]" required>
```

https://css-tricks.com/form-validation-part-1-constraint-validation-html/

Comment: Try `pattern="^[^=]"` [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fthmvLp/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `[^=]+` pattern for `type="email"` and `type="text"` here as the *pattern* attibute regexes are not applied to `type="number"` fields (and you can't type nor paste `=` into a numeric field):

```html
<form>
  <input name="email" pattern="[^=]+" type="email" placeholder="Email" required="">
  <input name="last name" pattern="[^=]+" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
  <input name="idnumber" type="number" placeholder="ID Number">
  <input type="Submit">
</form>
```

The `pattern="[^=]+"` translates into `/^(?:[^=]+)$/` regex (with `u` modifier in Chrome and FireFox) and matches a string that consists of 1+ chars other than `=`.

Comment: Ace work, No way these type fields can be hacked in any way? Just liked the idea of the pattern on top just for extra security

Comment: @Gracie To get extra security, implement additional checks on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't let them press that button, here is an example of not allowing them to even enter the = sign anywhere in the textbox. There is a second example of not allowing it to be the first character too.

```js
window.notEqual = function notEqual(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  return charCode != 61;
}

window.notEqualAtStart = function notEqualAtStart(evt, target) {
  if (target.value != '')
    return true;

  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  return charCode != 61;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return window.notEqual(event)" />

<input type="text" onkeypress="return window.notEqualAtStart(event, this)" />
```